# Which port does plotly uses by default?

Tags: plotly, port

I am having some issues working with plotly and docker containers. But before that I would like to ask a simple question:

What port does plotly uses to display its plots? (Is there a default port?)

EDIT: I run some experiments and plotly display results on a different port every time...which causes problems for me if I ever want to do this from inside a container

Comment: May be it's 8050

Comment: I am running an experiment in a virtual environment and I got 38151... I wonder if the virtual environment has some effect on this

Comment: Do you have somewhere a line with "app.run_server(debug=True)"? You can change it to "app.run_server(debug=True, port=8050)".